Error builind bcolz wheels on pip install bquery
Getting error when installing bquery both in my virtual environment and when directly on my terminal, on windows laptop.
This is happening on a peer's laptop too.
command : pip install bquery
pip version - 24.3.1
python version - 3.13.0

Error
Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects(bcolz)


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Please, show us text, not screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code block. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, shapes, sizes, positions, etc).

bquery is only compatible with Python 2.7, 3.5 - 3.7. It doesn't support your Python version (3.13). You can find a similar package that is maintained as this hasn't been maintained in 5 years. But if you must use this, downgrade your Python to a supported version.
